# How is "seguir" used to mean "still"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos

I know *seguir* means 'to follow', 'to continue'. However I've seen it many times being used to mean **'still'** or at least translating to 'still'.

For example:

> Mi hijo sigue en Londres por el trabajo <sub>My son is still in London for work</sub>
>
> Sigue lloviendo <sub>It is still raining</sub>

What is the proper way/grammer to use it while using *seguir* to mean 'still'?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Like "Mi hijo sigue en Londres por el trabajo" -> My son is still in London for work, and "sigue lloviendo" -> It is still raining

Comment: *Still* in this context means *todavía* or *aún*.

Comment: Yes I get that part, what my problem is the grammar involved

Comment: The literal translation makes sense, if sounding a bit stilted - `My son continues in London for work.` `It continues raining.` just think of it as in Spanish, to continue [doing] something is a way of expressing something is still happening.

Comment: You have cited the proper grammar used on its own or followed by another verb. From Spanish to English, the idiomatic translation is "still", as you have said. That said for the London one, you can **also** translate it as: "My son is still living in London", too. As living there is implied by the Spanish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you know the literal meaning of "seguir", which in the case of your question would be "to continue". While I'm not a big fan of literal translations, if you translate these sentences it still makes sense:

> Mi hijo sigue en Londres

Would be:

> My son *continues* in London

You just need to accept the fact that different languages use different constructions in their sentences.

By the way, you can also say:

> Mi hijo aún/todavía está en Londres

The only difference would be that this sounds like there's a certain stress on the fact that it's been a pretty long time and you're awaiting his return, but this is very subtle and doesn't need to apply at all times.

As to how to construct sentences in this manner, I think it'l be best for you to check up all the meanings of the verb "seguir", you'll notice there are quite a few:

> ## seguir
>
> `Del lat. vulg. *sequīre, y este del lat. sequi 'seguir', con la t. de ire 'ir'.`
>   1. tr. Ir después o detrás de alguien. U. t. c. intr.
>   2. tr. Ir en busca de alguien o algo; dirigirse, caminar hacia él o ello.
>   3. tr. Proseguir o continuar en lo empezado.
>   4. tr. Ir en compañía de alguien. Vine con él y le seguí siempre.
>   5. tr. Profesar o ejercer una ciencia, arte o estado.
>   6. tr. Dirigir la vista hacia un objeto que se mueve y mantener la visión de él.
>   7. tr. Observar atentamente el curso de un negocio o los movimientos de alguien o algo.
>   8. tr. Tratar o manejar un negocio o pleito, haciendo las diligencias conducentes para su logro.
>   9. tr. Conformarse, convenir, ser del dictamen o parcialidad de alguien.
>   10. tr. Perseguir, acosar o molestar a alguien; ir en su busca o alcance. Seguir una fiera.
>   11. tr. Imitar o hacer algo por el ejemplo que alguien ha dado de ello.
>   12. tr. Dirigir algo por camino o método adecuado, sin apartarse del intento.
>   13. prnl. Dicho de una cosa: Inferirse o ser consecuencia de otra.
>   14. prnl. Dicho de una cosa: Suceder a otra por orden, turno o número, o ser continuación de ella.
>   15. prnl. Dicho de una cosa: Originarse o causarse de otra.

Our specific use case would be number 3:

> 3. tr. Proseguir o continuar en lo empezado.

Usually one would use [seguir] + [gerundio] like "Sigue estudiando" or "sigo buscando", but our case is a bit specific and special, when we say something "sigue estando aquí", we don't need the "estar" verb in the sentence, so we end up with just "sigue aquí".

Comment: Thanks, but what I really want to understand is how to construct sentences that mean something is/was/will/would still be / being done using seguir

Comment: @kyonkopa added some more details

Comment: So can we say `sigues siendo bonita` could be rephrased as `sigues bonita`?

Comment: hmm, now you made me doubt, i have to think a bit about it, i feel like those two sentences are not completely equal :/ Probably has to do with the fact that spanish has two "to be"s, "ser" and "estar", i'd argue my point only really applies to "estar" and not "ser", if anybody else has input on this I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: I think this proposition is correct from the examples I've seen so far, and that is why I'm concerned about **how** to use it properly, in most cases when the "to be" verb is `estar` it is dropped.

Comment: @kyonkopa rephrased the "to be" thing to say "estar", i feel pretty confident about this. (i'm a native spanish speaker btw)

Comment: I would not translate this as: My son continues in London. continue is usually an active verb: He continues living in London. or:is still living in London.

Comment: @Lambie while it may not be 100% correct english, it's understandable and gets to the point, after all literal translating is never a good idea.

Comment: @kyonkopa By the way, if this answer solved your question i'd appreciate the tick of approval ;) if not, i'll be happy to expand on it with any further doubts.

Comment: @BrianH. One more thing, how to properly them in the past, I'm guessing it would be in the imperfect tense

Comment: you guessed right, `Mi hijo seguía en Londres`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see it for an English speaker is recalling the verb `to keep`. In general, we can say that

> Seguir + ando/endo = Keep + ing.

So

> Sigue lloviendo = it keeps raining.

Check that it is exactly the same structure (verb+ing). It's not weird.

Of course, this can be reworded as `It is still raining`, and many others.

Comment: The London sentence cannot be translated using keep.

Comment: hmm, good point. It's an ellipsis of "sigue estando en Londres". However, you're right, that doesn't fit either. In that case, "seguir" means "continue" or "stay".